# JavaScript ответы на вопросы

Tags: javascript

Пишу helper на JavaScript подскажите, где я допускаю ошибку

```
var dict = ['вопрос1', 'вопрос2'
];//добавим вопросы
var send = dict.length; //сосчитаем длину массива вопросов
var ans = ['ответ1', 'ответ2'
];//добавим ответы
var answer = ans.length;//сосчитаем длину массива ответов
 

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.body == dict[send]) {
        msg.reply(ans[answer]);
       
    }
        
});
```

Когда я пишу вопрос1 я не получаю ответ1
Скрипт работает только в таком виде, но вопрос2 разумеется от не будет учитывать

```
var dict = ['вопрос1', 'вопрос2'
];//добавим вопросы
var ans = ['ответ1', 'ответ2'
];//добавим ответы
 


client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.body == dict[0]) {
        msg.reply(ans[0]);
       
    }
        
});
```

Comment: `dict[send]` -> `dict[send - 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом примере:

```
dict[send]
```

всегда будет `undefined` так как он возвращает элемент массива по индексу а `send` является длинной и поэтому на 1 больше чем последний индекс

Чтобы узнать индекс вопроса в массиве можно использовать [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  const index = dict.indexOf(msg.body)
  if (index > -1) { // то есть такой элемент есть в массиве
    msg.reply(ans[index]);
  }
});
```

Comment: А как учитывать регистр? Вопрос может быть задан с другим регистром напимер ВоПрос1

Comment: можно все строки хранить в нижнем регистре и переводить входящий вопрос в нижний
```const index = dict.indexOf(msg.body.toLowerCase())```